# HTML and CSS: Getting the image to fit and float in the container

Tags: html, css, image

I'm been struggling with getting an image to fit in this table I made using CSS:

[image: Page layout]

I've tried to float it to the center and reduce the size of the image but it I've tried to float it to the center and reduce the size of the image but it messes up the table. The HTML code and CSS is below. I tried in the CSS to display it as a block and then change some of its properties but it still doesn't fit in the table or look right.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
<head>
<title>3 Column CSS Layout</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new.css">
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="menu">Navigation
<ul>
<li><a href="web1.html"> Link to page 1 </a> </li>
<li><a href="web2.html"> Link to page 2 </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">Content of page 2 </div>
<img src="dennis.jpg>
<div id="action">More content of page 2</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
text-align:center;
  }

div#page {
border:1px solid purple;
width:755px;
margin:50px auto;
padding:5px;
text-align:left;
position:relative;
  }

div#header {
border:2px solid black;
width:750px;
height:30px;
  }

div#navi {
border:2px solid black;
width:150px;
float:left; 
margin:10px 0 10px 5px;
height:500px;
}

div#content {
border:2px solid black;
width:400px;
margin:10px 0 10px 175px;
min-height:500px;
_height:500px
  }

div#action {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
right:10px;
border:2px solid black;
width:150px; 
margin:0;
height:500px;
  }

div#footer {
border:2px solid black;
width:750px;
height:30px;
  }

img {
display: block;
float: center;
height: 55%;
width: 50%;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include a picture of what the issue you are experiencing is. I am not sure what you want done when I cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: I can't insert images because I do not have the reputation needed. Check out the gyanzo link for the image. Sorry about that and any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to position an image element (or any element) in the center of parent element of any width and height, perhaps using `display: flex` in parent element and `margin: auto` in child element could work.

Comment: See an example: https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/full/POJGdx/ — an image takes 100% width but at most 200px in the second column of three. Try to resize the window randomly to see how it fits. Is it close to what you are looking for?

Comment: I kinda understand what you are saying but, I don't really get what you mean by parent element and child element. its an online class and this stuff isn't explained so I'm not sure where display: flex goes in CSS

Comment: You have a typo in the very first line `<!DOCTYPE html`

Comment: When I copied it somehow it didn't get closed but rest assured it is fixed on my end. Thanks

Comment: try this as a place to start: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/